# Datastore quota showing different(irrelevant) statistics upon time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I was trying out google Cloud Platform for my project and was performing trial operations on app engine with data store as database.I have never used or uploaded any huge data to database neither I have done any large queries today but when I checked out the quota usage its showing high usage,operation,trasfer statistics upto 8 GB and 6 Million operations,reads writes etc.I was shocked to see such a huge usage because all I have is 2 rows of data(15kb) and a table.
Its very disappointing for me, because once the billing is enabled and incidents like this happens it will be a big concern for me because I have have to employ other codes to track usage within our self.
I am kind of sure its not my fault because the quota statistics showing decrease usage statistics with time.I'm attaching the quota usage photo with this question.Does anyone else came across this situation ?
[image: First data]

[image: Second data]

[image: Third Data]

Comment: It sounds like it could be related to the known [GAE issue 7627](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7627&q=Type%3DDefect%20quota&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log), you may want to star it.

Comment: I thought it as a datastore issue,but now my cloud storage Class A operations are also changing.So its an app engine issue.Is it affected projects individually ?as per your link the Issue is reported in 2012 and yet google haven't cleared it?

Comment: I have many different apps on App Engine for 7 years now, and I never saw such problems. It's hard to say why you see this, but I suspect that there may be an issue with your code.

Comment: Dan, 4 people have starred this issue in 4 years out of tens of thousands of developers who ran apps on App Engine every day.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Yes, but just like most stats, that could be intrepreted in a pile of different ways. I also said it *could* be related, not that it *is* related.

Comment: @neo: is you app still functional when such quota exceeded info is reported? Is this a paid app? Does it have a daily budget set?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin. at first when i saw this, i too thought it was issue with my code, but then i realized that even my app engine is not active(google will stop app engine when there are no requests for specific time) that it had to start when i requested an operation.I know, I trust google and its some stupid bug that caused this

Comment: @DanCornilescu no its not a paid app so no budget set.Its just a trial app i created to run some test

Comment: @AndreiVolgin quality of a service is not just how many peoples are happy with successful operation but also how seriously they take care of a user that is unsatisfied

Comment: @neo: There are hundreds of thousands of apps running on GAE. What are the chances that you are the only one experiencing this bug?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I don't know whether I'm the only one but trust me it was a bug... not my mistake.pls look at each photos I uploaded ....there is 3 of the above .each one taken after other.my quotas are decreasing with time.any more proof needed to think it as a bug ?